Disable mouseover Autodesk Viewer Online - Inspector tool - Developper tool
Good day all,
I want to share a DWG file with the Autodesk Online Free viewer. My file includes rasters. With the viewer online, every layer is highlighted when mouse is put over. It's ok with polylines, but since there's a raster in the back, the screen becomes all orange and you can't see the details of the raster correctly anymore.
I'd like to know if there's a way to disable the, I believe, mouseover function with the developper tool in the browser (Chrome, Edge, etc.)
Here's an example of a shared file to remove the "mouseover" function in the developper tool.
https://autode.sk/4e99xPs
I searched on Google if anyone has done the same. Couldn't find any solution.
I found the following, but it's a different platform.
https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/viewer-tip-disable-mouse-hover-highlight
I tried removing the event listeners (mouseover, mouseup, mouse...) in the developper tool, but nothing changed.
I am not a programmer, so if a solution is found, please share a detailed procedure.

You can use CSS to remove mouseover event for that page:
#viewer-wrapper canvas {
    pointer-events: none;
}

You can click the Elements tab in devtools, then find and click the <canvas> element. At the right Styles panel, add this line pointer-events: none in #viewer-wrapper canvas element.

Please note this only take effect when you keep devtools open, and it can't be saved when you close devtools or refresh the page.

Thanks for the reply @Yu Zhou. This is a good start well explained. However, it seems that activating this, I can't scroll, zoom, move the map anymore. Would there be a way to still be able to move around (zoom and pan) while deactivating the background color over ?

I'm not familiar with Autodesk Viewer. What about find <canvas> element and add pointer-events: none in #viewer-wrapper canvas? The map can still zoom, move and so on and it won't become all orange. Please check my updated answer.

Awesome! Thank you very much! This is exactly what I was looking for! I can now move around on the map without having this background color appears with the mouse.
Short detailed answer with picture and step by step for a non programmer. On Point!
